# How to install Git-Flow on Amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: git-flow, amazon-linux

What is the proper way to install Git-Flow on Amazon Linux AMI ?

I have tried without success :

```
yum install git-flow
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found it

```
sudo yum upgrade
sudo yum install gitflow
```